# Getting FileNotFoundException / EISDIR

Tags: java, android, file, exception

I get this error

> java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   /data/data/com.example.app/cache/news.xml: open failed:
>   EISDIR (Is a directory)

using this code

```
try {
  File cache = ctx.getCacheDir();
  String s = cache.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + path;
  File f = new File(s);
  File pf = f.getParentFile();
  if (pf != null) {
    pf.mkdirs();
  } 
  if ( (pf.exists()) && (pf.isDirectory()) ) {           
    if ( (!f.exists()) || (!f.isFile()) ) {
      f.createNewFile();
    }
    if ( (f.exists()) || (f.isFile()) ) {
      FileOutputStream os = null;        
      os = new FileOutputStream(s, false);            
      if (os != null) {
        SharedCode.sharedWriteTextFileToStream(str, os);                
      }
      os.flush();
      os.close();
    }
  }  
}  
catch (IOException e) {
  String s = e.toString();
}
```

**Update** Adding code to delete the directory (f any) matching the wanted file name + correct usage of mkdirs appears to have solved the problem. Accepted closest answer.

Comment: Have you declared the `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission?

Comment: does path includes the file name ?

Comment: @giorasch Yes it does

Comment: @AndyRes Yes I have. (Althought I not offhand sure that is needed for writing to app's own cache folder.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`mkdirs()` creates not only the directories which lead to the file, but also a directory with the path the file points to. That's why the `createNewFile()` fails. You need to call `mkdirs()` on the parent file instead:

```
File parent = f.getParentFile();
if (parent != null) parent.mkdirs();
```

Comment: I have changed over to use your code now. But I still get the same error. I will try look into detetcing if there's a directory having the same name as the file I am creating, and if so, possibly trying to remove it first. (Torgther with your solution, that should solve the problem)

Answer (score 1):

please note

```
f.mkdirs();
```

you need to check the return value of this statement. If true then proceed otherwise path is not existing.

Comment: @giorashc ya right. i just showing the way to so that he can find the right answer on his own. so that we do not need to do spoon feeding

Comment: I will add code to check, but just for reference, it is true.